# Chunk txt file into an html table with bash

Tags: html, bash, awk

I have a ~600 line .txt file, all.txt.  I want to turn it into an HTML table with two columns where the first column contains the entire contents of all.txt with exactly five lines in each row (so the table would have about 120 rows total).  Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
A=10
B=5
len=`wc -l < all.txt`
len2=$((len / 5))

while [ $A -le $len2 ]; do
    head -$A all.txt | tail -$B |
    awk '
    BEGIN{print " "} 
    {printf("<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>\n")}
    END{print " "}
    '
    let A+=5
done
```

As you can see, this is really just a shell of a script, and I'm not sure what to with awk inside the loop.  Is using awk inside a control structure like this even the best way to do it?  Is bash even a reasonable way to do it?

Comment: Can you perhaps include some sample data and your intended output in the question, rather than just describing it? Way easier to test solutions against something "real".

Comment: The right way to do it is an awk script on it's own, adding a shell loop around it just makes it harder, slower, and worse in every other way (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)). Post concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for the link -- this answers my real question.  I ended up implementing something in Python to do the job: `f=open('all.txt')
lines=f.readlines()
index = 0
start = 0
end = 5

print '<table style="width:100%">'

while index <=605:
 print '<tr><td>'
 print '<br>'.join(lines[start:end])
 start = end
 end += 5
 index = start
 print '</td><td></td></tr>'

print '</table>'`

Comment: @Chandrew that's too bad, an awk script as you originally asked for would probably have been briefer, clearer, more portable, and more efficient. Oh well...

Answer (score 1):

`sed` alternative

```
 $ sed -e '5~5a</td>\n<td></td>\n</tr>' -e '1~5i<tr>\n<td>' <(seq 15)

<tr>
<td>
1
2
3
4
5
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
6
7
8
9
10
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
11
12
13
14
15
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You properly only need awk:

```
awk 'NR%5 == 1{printf "%s<tr><td>", NR > 1 ? "</td><td></td></tr>" : ""}1' all.txt
```

Might need to add `END{print "</td><td></td></tr>"}` at the end.